# How to hide the table when i click button using js?

Tags: javascript

First of all the view page shows only two buttons leave and attendance.
when i click the leave button i shows the table(tb2).and again i click the that button it hide the table
[image]

When i click the attendance i display the another table(tb3).it is same as previous
[image]

Now for me i want when i click the leave button the opened attendance table should be closed and it same for the attendance button.

My code:

```
var click = document.getElementById('clickme');
click.addEventListener('click', myfunction);

function myfunction() {
   var tablewrap = document.getElementById('tb2');
   tablewrap.classList.toggle('show')

};


var click = document.getElementById('click');
click.addEventListener('click', myfunction);

function myfunction() {
   var tablewrap = document.getElementById('tb3');
   tablewrap.classList.toggle('show')
};
```

Comment: Using jquery instead of plain javascript will be better for DOM manipulations

Comment: no need  toggle for hide and show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var click = document.getElementById('clickme');
click.addEventListener('click', myfunction);

function myfunction() {
   var tablewrap = document.getElementById('tb2');
   tablewrap.classList.toggle('show');

   document.getElementById('tb3').classList.remove('show');


};


var click = document.getElementById('click');
click.addEventListener('click', myfunction);

function myfunction() {
   var tablewrap = document.getElementById('tb3');
   tablewrap.classList.toggle('show');

document.getElementById('tb2').classList.remove('show')

};
```

Remove the classes explicitly

Comment: do you want to close the attendance table always on click of leave button and vice versa?

Comment: i changed  it vivek and i got result :)  remove if condition to both of them

Comment: Ok i have assumed that you only want to close the attendance table on click of leave button when the leave table is also opened so both will be hidden, which is wrong..
I have updated the answer as well. :)

Comment: if i click attendance button it will open the  attendance table and when i click the leave button the attendance table must closed and leave table is open and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery it will make things easy.

```js
$('#btnLeave').click(function(){
   if($('#tblLeave').css('display')=='none'){
      $('#tblLeave').css('display','block');
   } else {
      $('#tblLeave').css('display','none');
   }
});

$('#btnAttendance').click(function(){
   if($('#tblAttendance').css('display')=='none'){
      $('#tblAttendance').css('display','block');
   } else {
      $('#tblAttendance').css('display','none');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnLeave">Leave</button>
<button id="btnAttendance">Attendance</button>

<br><br>
<table id="tblLeave" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%; display: none">
  <thead>
    <td>Leave<td>
  </thead>
<table>
<br>
<table id="tblAttendance" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%; display: none">
  <thead>
    <td>Attendance<td>
  </thead>
<table>
```

Or Alternating the show and hide of two tables

```js
$('#btnLeave').click(function(){
   if($('#divLeave').css('display')=='none'){
      $('#divLeave').css('display','block');
      $('#divAttendance').css('display','none');
   }
});

$('#btnAttendance').click(function(){
   if($('#divAttendance').css('display')=='none'){
      $('#divAttendance').css('display','block');
      $('#divLeave').css('display','none');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnLeave">Leave</button>
<button id="btnAttendance">Attendance</button>

<br><br>
<div id="divLeave">
  <table id="tblLeave" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
      <td>Leave<td>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<div id="divAttendance" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 47px; width: 100%">
  <table id="tblAttendance" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%">
    <thead>
      <td>Attendance<td>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```